# Spring Data CRUD Repository: save method does not work

Tags: java, spring, jpa

**This is not about Spring Boot at all.**

*My English could be better.*

Using below Config for Spring Data I'm trying to execute DML requests.

Exactly `CrudRepository#save` method.

However executing Spring's CrudRepository#save method I'm getting next:

1. ONLY Selects are logged by `hibernate.show_sql` feature.
2. No "insert" or "update" statements are being executed as to hibernate.show_sql logging.
3. No changes at database at all.

====================================================

Not sure but it looks like a Transaction issue.

Seems that there is no transaction at that point,

so out of transaction CRUD Repos is not able to execute DML requests,
including `CrudRepository#save`.

Maybe it is something wrong with configuration?
Have a look please and feel free to ask for any additional info.

**UPDATE:**
The next bad-practice workaround helped me to reach the "Update" statements execution.

```
//(autowired, shared entity manager)
entityManager.joinTransaction();
repository.save(user);
```

However it is still a bad practice approach. In this case Spring's purpose is lost.
Anyway it is required for me to use Declarative Code-based Transaction managment.
Question is still open:
**What is wrong with my config? @Transactional annotation still doesn't work**

User domain entity:

```
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User
{
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id_pk", length = 11)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int idPk;

    @Column(name = "user_id", length = 25, nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String userId;

    @Column(name = "email_addr", length = 120)
    private String email;
}
```

Domain-specific Spring Data CRUD Repository declaration:

```
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Integer> {
  //nothing specific
}
```

Spring **(Boot-less)** Code-based configuration:

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "***",
        transactionManagerRef = "jpaTransactionManager")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class DataConfig
{
    @Bean
    public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory()
    {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        factory.setPackagesToScan(DOMAIN_ENTITY_SCAN_PACKAGE);
        factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(getVendorAdapter());
        factory.afterPropertiesSet();
        return factory.getObject();
    }

    private HibernateJpaVendorAdapter getVendorAdapter()
    {
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        vendorAdapter.setShowSql(Boolean.TRUE);
        return vendorAdapter;
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaTransactionManager jpaTransactionManager()
    {
        JpaTransactionManager txManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        txManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory());
        txManager.afterPropertiesSet();
        return txManager;
    }
}
```

Comment: Change the id to a non-primitive type so that it can take a null value, otherwise it will always be PK 0 when you go to insert

Comment: @JLazar0 thanks for the advice however this point has nothing to do with the issue I've described above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I've found a solution for my case.

Since I'm using Spring without its Boot part
I had to configure custom *WebApplicationInitializer* to let Spring manage application entry point:

```
public class MainWebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer
{
    @Override
    public void onStartup(final ServletContext sc)
    {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext root = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        root.register(WebAppConfiguration.class, DataConfig.class);
        sc.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(root));
        
        ...other not related code ommited
    }
}
```

So because I've registered both Config Classes (*WebAppConfiguration.class*, *DataConfig.class*) using *AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext#register*
I thought annotating configs with *@Configuration* would be Redundand.

And I was wrong at that point.

To register *TransactionManager* correctly you SHOULD annotate your Jpa Config class with *@Configuration*.

Thus I've managed to annotate my config classes with *@Configuration* and this solved my issue.

Now Spring CRUD Repositories are able to run DML queries to DB (with help of #save methods).
Precisely talking: now Repositories are able to open own transactions and run required queries in terms of these transactions.

Comment: works for me! I met this problem in test environment. I created config with all beans such DataSource, EntityManagerFactory, PlatformTransactionManager. Then I added this config in '@ContextConfiguration'. But save operation didn't work. So I mark config with '@Configuration' and it works like a charm. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I didnot get this, how you are initializing the datasource properties ? I could not see in your given code.

```
factory.setDataSource(dataSource());
```

You should be designing you Configuration class like below. Use both the :

```
entityManagerFactoryRef="entityManagerFactory",
transactionManagerRef="jpaTransactionManager"
```

Read the hibernate properties from a yaml or properties file.

And set your datasource

**Configuration class : DataConfig**

```
/**
 * @author Som
 *
 */

@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages="package-name",
                       entityManagerFactoryRef="entityManagerFactory",
                       transactionManagerRef="jpaTransactionManager")
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:application.yml" })
public class DataConfig {
    
    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;
    
    @Value("${datasource.myapp.maxPoolSize:10}")
    private int maxPoolSize;
    
    
    /**
     * Populate DataSourceProperties object directly from application.yml 
     *       *
     */
    
    @Bean
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "datasource.myapp")
    public DataSourceProperties dataSourceProperties(){
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }
    
    
    /**
     * Configure HikariCP pooled DataSource.
     * 
     */
    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DataSourceProperties dataSourceProperties = dataSourceProperties();
        HikariDataSource dataSource = (HikariDataSource) DataSourceBuilder
                .create(dataSourceProperties.getClassLoader())
                .driverClassName(dataSourceProperties.getDriverClassName())
                .url(dataSourceProperties.getUrl())
                .username(dataSourceProperties.getUsername())
                .password(dataSourceProperties.getPassword())
                .type(HikariDataSource.class)
                .build();
        
        dataSource.setMaximumPoolSize(maxPoolSize);
        return dataSource;
    }
    
    
    /**
     * Entity Manager Factory setup.
     * 
     */
    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() throws NamingException {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
        factoryBean.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "package-name" });
        factoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter());
        factoryBean.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties());
        return factoryBean;
    }
    
    
    
    /**
     * Provider specific adapter.
     * 
     */
    @Bean
    public JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter() {
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter hibernateJpaVendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        return hibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
    }
 
    /**
     * Hibernate properties.
     * 
     */
    private Properties jpaProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", environment.getRequiredProperty("datasource.myapp.hibernate.dialect"));
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", environment.getRequiredProperty("datasource.myapp.hibernate.hbm2ddl.method"));
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("datasource.myapp.hibernate.show_sql"));
        properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("datasource.myapp.hibernate.format_sql"));
        if(StringUtils.isNotEmpty(environment.getRequiredProperty("datasource.myapp.defaultSchema"))){
            properties.put("hibernate.default_schema", environment.getRequiredProperty("datasource.myapp.defaultSchema"));
        }
        return properties;
    }
 
    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public PlatformTransactionManager jpaTransactionManager(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
        JpaTransactionManager txManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        txManager.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);
        return txManager;
    }

}
```

**application.yaml**

```
server:
  port: 8081
  servlet:
    context-path: /CRUDApp
---
spring:
  profiles: local,default
datasource:
  myapp:
    url: jdbc:h2:~/test
    username: SA
    password:
    driverClassName: org.h2.Driver
    defaultSchema:
    maxPoolSize: 10
    hibernate:
      hbm2ddl.method: create-drop
      show_sql: true
      format_sql: true
      dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
---
```

Comment: Thank you, Som. 
I hid the #dataSource method since it's internal work has nothing to do with the issue above.

It is something that is definitely not about Data Source since all communication with db is working correctly in terms of DataSource config.

And as I mentioned in UPDATE above: with entityManager#joinTransaction everything works fine, although it is a bad practice anyway.


Thanks, will try to specify entityManagerFactoryRef explicitly.

Comment: @MykytaChelombitko : No problem .  Aah I see. Yeah it is not definitely about the datasource , I understand that. You can try once in your configuration class with both  `entityManagerFactoryRef` and `transactionManagerRef` as I have described in my code.

Comment: Unfortunately that didnt help.

Comment: The interesting thing is that Transactional annotation seems to be working.
Why? Because I'm not able to join the transaction if I dont use Transactional over the method/class. So it looks like a difference between transactions context or something like that. Not sure tho.

Comment: @MykytaChelombitko : Strange this case, I am using this same configuration for years in one of my project.  And what you mean by @ Transactional working, you missed that earlier in your service class or service methods ? Its better to use this anno in your service class. Good to see your issue got resolved.

Comment: Earlier above I mentioned that "Looks like something wrong with Transactional annotation, it seems to be not working etc.".
But now I realized that it is something wrong with transactions context since with help of Transactional over the method - some transaction is being created and started, so I was able to join it manually, however it is just unseen by CRUD Repos that I'm calling to save User. Thats why that Repository cannot save entity - its just out of actual transaction that is being created by Transactional over the method.

Comment: Sorry but the issue is not resolved at that point. It is just a theory that would possibly help me to solve it. For now I've still got no idea what to do with that :)

Comment: Hmm OK .. May be do you have some logs ? Not sure but this is how I have inmplemented in my case. The only difference I have is that I use JPA repo and you are using CRUD repo .. with JPA repo just having some extra functionalities like flushing the persistence context.  Also tell me one thing you are using the #transaction anno as a class header or method header.

Comment: There are only hibernate.show_sql queries are looged, other logss I've turned off intentionally to avoid misleading.

I'm using Transactional anno over the method specifically. I've tried both ways - no success tho. I don't think it is principal here. 

Thank you for your tryings.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220555/discussion-between-mykyta-chelombitko-and-som).